# Grails/GORM BigInteger Unsigned Rejected

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm getting the following error:

```
| Error 2014-08-18 11:25:00,324 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'my.package.Content' on field 'fileNameLookup': rejected value [16731516642733300018]; codes [my.package.Content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch.error,my.package.Content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch,content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch.error,content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.my.package.Content.fileNameLookup,typeMismatch.fileNameLookup,typeMismatch.java.lang.Long,typeMismatch]; arguments [fileNameLookup]; default message [Could not convert number [16731516642733300018] of type [java.math.BigInteger] to target class [java.lang.Long]: overflow]
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'my.package.Content' on field 'fileNameLookup': rejected value [16731516642733300018]; codes [my.package.Content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch.error,my.package.Content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch,content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch.error,content.fileNameLookup.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.my.package.Content.fileNameLookup,typeMismatch.fileNameLookup,typeMismatch.java.lang.Long,typeMismatch]; arguments [fileNameLookup]; default message [Could not convert number [16731516642733300018] of type [java.math.BigInteger] to target class [java.lang.Long]: overflow]
Line | Method
->>    6 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Domain class:

```
    package my.package

// need to fix constraints

class Content {
    // int id
    Long fileNameLookup

    static mapping = {
        version false
        fileNameLookup column: 'file_name_lookup', type:org.hibernate.type.LongType, class: Long
    }

    static constraints = {
        fileNameLookup(nullable:true, display:false, editable: false)
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.groovy:

```
import my.package.Content

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Content(fileNameLookup:16731516642733300018).save(failOnError:true)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

I tried Long, BigInteger, Integer, etc... and burnt hours on this trying to figure out how to get this bigint(20) unsigned to save into the test db. How do i tell Grails/Gorm that the number is a bigint(20) so that it can handle it properly regardless of the database that i'm using?

Comment: Have you tried with a number you can fit in a `Long`?  As the error says, `16731516642733300018` is too big to fit in a `Long`, so you get  overflow

Comment: I thank you for pointing that out, what i want to know is what the right type is so that i can fit numbers of that size in the database.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the `Long fileNameLookup` field is too small to store that number.  Does changing the type to a `java.math.BigInteger` give you a different error message?

Comment: Using the H2 database I couldn't get it to work, i knew that it would work with MySQL since the code that I used to generate that 20 digit number was originally developed for MySQL. I wrote a groovy class that handles the conversion for me so that I can use any database without having the code dependent on MySQL only. What I did after changing the datasource was add sqlType: 'bigint(20) unsigned' to the mappings. I was really hoping to get this to work with any database but the field is too long for any of the fields in H2.

Comment: Some databases do not support unsigned bigint column types, H2 being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Long.MAX_VALUE is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Your number is too big for it. Using BigDecimal should fix this.

```
BigDecimal fileNameLookup
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still getting errors. I'm not sure why I have to save a bigint(20) as a decimal. Is there no type of bigint in grails/gorm?

Comment: I went ahead and tried this again, this time i added the sqlType: 'decimal(20,0)' and it worked. I'm not sure that I like this approach of treating this as a number vs. treating this as an integer used in a where clause in queries. I would ultimately like to use a bigint(20) unsigned regardless of platform.